# React - How to navigate using a custom component instead of react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a *rooms* list that I iterate, rendering the different rooms like this:

```
<Room room={room} key={room.id}/>
```

I want each room to redirect to their corresponding path (`/rooms/:id`). The only way of redirecting elements is via **react-router-dom** but I feel there must be a better way of achieving redirection in this case.

Comment: react-router-dom works very well, why can't you use it? You could manage the routes through the backend though

Comment: Would it be implemented like <Link to="my-route"><Room.../></Link>?

Comment: I've tried that but not all the rendered rooms allow me that (some are clickable and some are not, I don't really know why tho)

Comment: <Link to="my-route"/> would be use to navigate to your route, you need to declare the routes before in between <Routes></Routes>. Check the documentation https://reactrouter.com/en/main or this tutorial, for example, https://blog.webdevsimplified.com/2022-07/react-router/

Comment: Yes! But in my case I want this: "<Room room={room} key={room.id}/>" to be clickable. Should I wrap that in the Link?

Comment: Maybe you could add more code because I'm not understanding your problem, you can make your component clickable but that's different from routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React router works fine, only thing you need is pass id to link

```
<Route path="/RoomsList/:roomId" element={<RoomCard/>}/>
```

in RoomCard you use hook

```
const {roomId} = useParams();
```

and change the component depending on the id.

Comment: Thanks! I will check on useParams. 